# How to rotate a pie chart by progressbar plugin counterclockwise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I use an open-source plugin in github, here is the link:
https://github.com/yxfanxiao/jQuery-plugin-progressbar

Please see the codes below:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery-plugin-progressbar.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery-plugin-progressbar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="progress-bar position"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar position" data-percent="60" data-duration="1000" data-color="#ccc,yellow"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar position" data-percent="20" data-color="#a456b1,#12b321"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="加载">
    <script>
        $(".progress-bar").loading();
        $('input').on('click', function () {
             $(".progress-bar").loading();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
;
(function ($) {
    $.fn.loading = function () {
        var DEFAULTS = {
            backgroundColor: '#b3cef6',
            progressColor: '#4b86db',
            percent: 75,
            duration: 2000
        };  

        $(this).each(function () {
            var $target  = $(this);

            var opts = {
            backgroundColor: $target.data('color') ? $target.data('color').split(',')[0] : DEFAULTS.backgroundColor,
            progressColor: $target.data('color') ? $target.data('color').split(',')[1] : DEFAULTS.progressColor,
            percent: $target.data('percent') ? $target.data('percent') : DEFAULTS.percent,
            duration: $target.data('duration') ? $target.data('duration') : DEFAULTS.duration
            };
            // console.log(opts);

            $target.append('<div class="background"></div><div class="rotate"></div><div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div><div class=""><span>' + opts.percent + '%</span></div>');

            $target.find('.background').css('background-color', opts.backgroundColor);
            $target.find('.left').css('background-color', opts.backgroundColor);
            $target.find('.rotate').css('background-color', opts.progressColor);
            $target.find('.right').css('background-color', opts.progressColor);

            var $rotate = $target.find('.rotate');
            setTimeout(function () {    
                $rotate.css({
                    'transition': 'transform ' + opts.duration + 'ms linear',
                    'transform': 'rotate(' + opts.percent * 3.6 + 'deg)'
                });
            },1);       

            if (opts.percent > 50) {
                var animationRight = 'toggle ' + (opts.duration / opts.percent * 50) + 'ms step-end';
                var animationLeft = 'toggle ' + (opts.duration / opts.percent * 50) + 'ms step-start';  
                $target.find('.right').css({
                    animation: animationRight,
                    opacity: 1
                });
                $target.find('.left').css({
                    animation: animationLeft,
                    opacity: 0
                });
            } 
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**CSS:**

```
.position {
  float: left;
  margin: 100px 50px;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.progress-bar div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.progress-bar div span {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  left: 12.5px;
  top: 12.5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.progress-bar .background {
  background-color: #b3cef6;
}
.progress-bar .rotate {
  clip: rect(0 50px 100px 0);
  background-color: #4b86db;
}
.progress-bar .left {
  clip: rect(0 50px 100px 0);
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #b3cef6;
}
.progress-bar .right {
  clip: rect(0 50px 100px 0);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #4b86db;
}

@keyframes toggle {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Note that you can download a zip-file from the link provided including those codes. As to be seen, originally the pie charts are rotating clockwise. All I need is to make them rotate counterclockwise. That was looking easy but I could not manage to do it for hours unfortunately. Any help or advise would be so appreciated! Thanks!!

Edit: Please note that the starting point (origin) of the animation should not be changed, should start from the top (north).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by multiplying your rotate value by its minus value; `-3.6` instead of `3.6`. You'd also have to update the CSS accordingly as otherwise it will start animating from bottom contrary to original version where it starts from top.
You can trick it via swapping left and right components, but that will affect the progress values less than 50%, thus you should add an else statement to handle that as well. 
Hence final JS file becomes like below;

**JS:**

```
;
(function ($) {
    $.fn.loading = function () {
        var DEFAULTS = {
            backgroundColor: '#f00',
            progressColor: '#adadad',
            percent: 75,
            duration: 2000
        };  

        $(this).each(function () {
            var $target  = $(this);

            var opts = {
            backgroundColor: $target.data('color') ? $target.data('color').split(',')[0] : DEFAULTS.backgroundColor,
            progressColor: $target.data('color') ? $target.data('color').split(',')[1] : DEFAULTS.progressColor,
            percent: $target.data('percent') ? $target.data('percent') : DEFAULTS.percent,
            duration: $target.data('duration') ? $target.data('duration') : DEFAULTS.duration
            };

            $target.append('<div class="background"></div><div class="rotate"></div>'+
                '<div class="left"></div>'+
                '<div class="right"></div><div class=""><span>' +
                + opts.percent + '%</span></div>');

            $target.find('.background').css('background-color', opts.backgroundColor);
            $target.find('.left').css('background-color', opts.backgroundColor);
            $target.find('.rotate').css('background-color', opts.progressColor);
            $target.find('.right').css('background-color', opts.progressColor);

            var $rotate = $target.find('.rotate');
            setTimeout(function () {    
                $rotate.css({
                    'transition': 'transform ' + opts.duration + 'ms linear',
                    'transform': 'rotateZ(' + -opts.percent * 3.6 + 'deg)'
                });
            },1);       

            if (opts.percent > 50) {
                var animationRight = 'toggle ' + (opts.duration / opts.percent * 50) + 'ms step-end';
                var animationLeft = 'toggle ' + (opts.duration / opts.percent * 50) + 'ms step-start';  
                $target.find('.left').css({
                    animation: animationRight,
                    opacity: 1
                });
                $target.find('.right').css({
                    animation: animationLeft,
                    opacity: 0
                });
            } 
            else {
                var animationRight = 'toggle ' + (opts.duration / opts.percent * 50) + 'ms step-end';
                var animationLeft = 'toggle ' + (opts.duration / opts.percent * 50) + 'ms step-start';  
                $target.find('.left').css({
                    animation: animationRight,
                    opacity: 0
                });
                $target.find('.right').css({
                    animation: animationLeft,
                    opacity: 1
                });
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Changing left/right is a great idea! I was playing with css all the time. Thanks.